# How to get MIN and MAX dates in a table in BusinessObjects Web Intelligence when table has a break?

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, business-objects

I have created a report in webi where I have patient data which is divided into two parts POST-Test & PRE-Test, each part has multiple Drawn DTTM (multiple results) and one single Dispense Event DTTM.

The business user doesn't want all the drawn date times or result but wants the Minimum drawn datetime for POST-Test and Maximum drawn datetime for PRE-Test. In the attached picture I want only the rows which are highlighted in yellow, not the rest of the info.

[image]

I am open for solution at Universe level too - Information Design Tool.

Environment: Web Intelligence 4.1 SP 8, IDT 4.1, & Database Oracle

Comment: HOW is the data divided into "two parts"? (POST-test and PRE-test?) Is there a separate column that classifies the rows as either POST-test or PRE-test? Is the "test" the same as the single row marked Dispense Event? (Are 'Drawn' and 'Dispense' classifiers in a column different from your "date-time"?)

Comment: I divided the data as per the requirement into two POST-test & PRE-test by creating a variable based on Dispense Event dttm object (=If [Drawn Datetime] < [Disp Event Datetime] Then "PRE" Else "POST") so now each of this have multiple drawn dates and we are looking to capture only one from each. Yes there is a separate column which show post and pre. The test can be same can differ. Not clear about your last question. thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for the situation. Here it is as follows:

I created three variables:

1. `Max Accession: =Max([Accession]) Where ([Variables].[Pre/Post] = "PRE") In ([Patient Birth Date])`
2. `Min Accession: =Min([Accession]) Where ([Variables].[Pre/Post] = "POST") In ([Patient Birth Date])`
3. `Accession Min/Max= If ([Accession]=[Min accession])Then 1 ElseIf ([Accession] = [Max accession]) Then 2 Else 0` (this will give 1 to the min accession, then 2 to max and finally 0 to the rest of them)

Last step: I applied the third variable to the table with condition to select all which are greater than 0.

Note:

1. The accession in the pre and post breaks are kind of numbers low to high
2. I gave Patient Birth Date as we don't have patient name or MRN in DEV environment, will replace it with patient name in PROD.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need something like this. Notice the WITH clause, in which I created some simulated inputs - not exactly your inputs, but similar in nature. Notice that the computation is done separately for each patient_id; in the inputs I simulated only one patient, but it works the same in all cases. In one pass over the base data, I use conditional analytic min and max for the two groups (PRE and POST) - the case expression within MIN and MAX does the separation into the two groups. Then in an outer query I select just two rows for each patient. Look at the output and compare to the input, then adapt for your actual table and column names.

Left unhandled: what happens if a "drawn" datetime is exactly equal to the "dispensed" datetime. If that cannot happen in your data, then, obviously, it doesn't need to be handled.

```
with
     inputs ( patient_id, dta, drawndttm, dispdttm ) as (
       select 1001, 'xhg', date '2017-03-23', date '2017-04-15' from dual union all
       select 1001, 'abc', date '2017-03-30', date '2017-04-15' from dual union all
       select 1001, 'xhg', date '2017-03-31', date '2017-04-15' from dual union all
       select 1001, 'zz3', date '2017-04-22', date '2017-04-15' from dual union all
       select 1001, 'ab3', date '2017-04-28', date '2017-04-15' from dual
     )
-- End of SIMULATED inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select    patient_id, dta, drawndttm, dispdttm, 
          case when drawndttm < dispdttm then 'PRE' else 'POST' end as classif
from      (
            select patient_id, dta, drawndttm, dispdttm,
                   max( case when drawndttm < dispdttm then drawndttm end ) 
                        over (partition by patient_id) as max_pre,
                   min( case when drawndttm > dispdttm then drawndttm end ) 
                        over (partition by patient_id) as min_post
            from   inputs
          )
where    drawndttm in (max_pre, min_post)
order by patient_id, drawndttm     --   if needed
;

PATIENT_ID DTA DRAWNDTTM DISPDTTM  CLASSIF
---------- --- --------- --------- -------
      1001 xhg 31-Mar-17 15-Apr-17 PRE 
      1001 zz3 22-Apr-17 15-Apr-17 POST
```

Comment: Thanks bro for your generous time and efforts really appreciate it, I was looking for an answer in Businessobject Web Intelligence tool.

Comment: @Ahmed - OK, understood - no worries. I am leaving the Answer here in case someone else has a similar problem but needs to solve it in SQL. I hope you are able to solve it in the BWI tool; sorry, I can't help with that (I don't even know what that is). Good luck!

Comment: @Ahmed: don't forget that if an answer looks good, you are encouraged to _upvote_ it (by clicking the up button adjacent to the answer). It is a nice way of thanking someone and marking material as helpful. You can do this on as many answers as you like (though it is not mandatory). You are additionally encouraged to _accept_ one answer by clicking the adjacent tick/check mark (you may accept your own answer if you wish). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done fairly easily in the report, without modifying the SQL or the universe.

I'm assuming that you want the Pre and Post for each patient, identified by the first column (`Patient ABO/RH`), so that's what I used in my formula below.  If that's not correct, then simply replace those references with the appropriate key.

There's a couple of ways to do it.  What I'm proposing here is simply grabbing the minimum Drawn date for rows categorized as Post, and maximum Drawn date for rows categorized as Pre.  First we create an indicator to identify the rows that meet that condition:

```
=If ([Drawn date] =  Min([Drawn date]) In ([Patient ABO/RN])  Where ([PrePost] = "POST") ) 
 Or ([Drawn date] =  Max([Drawn date]) In ([Patient ABO/RN])  Where ([PrePost] = "PRE")  )
 Then "Y" Else "N"
```

Drop this into your report block and both of your yellow rows should get a "Y", and the rest "N".  You can then apply a filter on the block for only the "Y" values, then remove the column doesn't it doesn't appear.

Comment: Thanks Joe tried something else, saw your reply late. Appreciate all your help.